# Keyboard commands to switch through videos in Processing

Tags: video, processing

I am working on a creative code project for school using **Processing**.

We have a series of 5 videos where each one is corresponding to a different key on the keyboard.

Does anyone have some quick code for this? simply pressing a button which pulls up the corresponding video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the place to ask for ready-made code, but for asking help with code you already wrote. Next time, try having a [reproducible example (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ready:

For now, here's an answer that may get you on the right track.

Take a look at the video (link) library to load and play your videos. You need to create a Movie object and play it using the [`play()` (link)](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Movie_play_.html) function.

The [`keyPressed()` (link)](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) function can be used to check if a certain `input()` has been pressed, though I am not sure how your 'Makey Makey' interacts with your computer. If you can make it press buttons on your keyboard, listen for those [`keyCode`s (link)](https://processing.org/reference/keyCode.html) in your `keyPressed()` function.

Comment: Thanks for helping this guy. Few people would have done this, and you did it the right way.